# What is the best way to convert key:value pairs from bytestring to string?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

Lets say I have a dict:

```
{b'Name': b'John', b'age': b'43'}
```

what would be the best way to convert that to:

```
{'Name': 'John', 'age': '43'}
```

(Considering that there can be any number of key:value pairs)

This is what I have right now:

```
new_d = dict()
old_d = {b'Name': b'John', b'age': b'43'}

for item in old_d:
    print(item, old_d[item])
    new_d[item.decode('ascii')] = old_d[item].decode('ascii')
    print(new_d)
```

Output:

```
{'Name': 'John', 'age': '43'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = { b'Name': b'John', b'age': b'43' }
d = { x.decode('ascii'): d.get(x).decode('ascii') for x in d.keys() }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x = {b'Name': b'John', b'age': b'43'}

y = {}

for key, value in x.items():
    y[key.decode("utf-8")] = value.decode("utf-8")

y
> {'Name': 'John', 'age': '43'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant test this right now, but you should be able to decode everything into a new dictionary. You should specify the encoding- I think UTF-8 is a good default.

```
enc = 'utf-8'
s = {k.decode(enc), v.decode(enc) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Nice one-liner. Though you mispelled the comma: s = {k.decode(enc): v.decode(enc) for k, v in d.items()}